# only blank page displays, no errors, no output

Tags: php, pdo

I'm new to PHP and databases and am currently battling blank pages. I tried to print the error messages on the web page, but no luck... Here's a sample PHP:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once("scripts/config.php");
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=".$dbhost.";dbname="".$dbname, $uname, $dbpw);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM DbTable";
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
echo $statement->execute();
?>
```

Why is this page coming up blank?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `How do I get PHP errors to display?` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: I looked at that and implemented the accepted answer; can't access php.ini on my host though.

Comment: What? You should work on a local environment where you have access to all necessary configuration files. You have a `ParseError` and you should be able to identify them easy with a proper code editor.

Comment: `";dbname="".$dbname` Say no more ... TYPO

Comment: `echo $statement->execute();` also isn't going to work. You need to fetch that result object.

Comment: In this case I just wanted to check whether the query was successful. It returns 1, so it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable error reporting in php.ini (search for the ERROR section).

Comment: Oh... As far as I know, I can't access php.ini on my host...

Comment: Only if its disabled - and that's so you can READ YOUR LOGS.

Comment: @TimB - you can check the ini settings from your PHP code.